# Round robin average waiting time

Tags: round-robin

Calculate the average waiting time of the processes with round-robin scheduling (**quantum = 3**) for the following processes with their arrival times and burst times.

```
  Process          Arrival time.        Burst time

     A                 0                    8
     B                 1.                   5
     C                 5                    2
     D                 8                    1
```

**Select one**:

- a. 8 seconds
- b. 4 seconds
- c. 6 seconds
- d. 24 seconds
- e. None of the above

How should I answer this question? I would like a detailed explanation with an answer.